# How to Ping explicitly from eth1 instead of eth0

Tags: linux, ping, eth0

I'm trying to execute a ping with eth1, but the program uses eth0(the default network device). Any tips, tricks, or alternate techniques available?

Comment: What does it mean to execute a ping "with" an interface exactly?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From the manual:

> ```
>   -I interface
>           interface is either an address, or an interface name.  If interface is an address, it sets source
>           address to specified interface address.  If interface in an interface name, it sets source inter‐
>           face  to  specified  interface.   For  ping6, when doing ping to a link-local scope address, link
>           specification (by the '%'-notation in destination, or by this option) is required.
> ```

So, answer is:

```
ping -I eth1 123.123.123.123
```

Comment: NOTE: ** Be careful when using ping -I, it isn't always unintrusive. If you have a bond0 (teaming NICs) and you ping one of the slaves it will block the network connection until the ping stops ..

Answer (score 9):

Use the `-I` option -

```
-I interface address
          Set  source address to specified interface address. Argument may
          be numeric IP address or name of device. When pinging IPv6 link-
          local address this option is required.
```

ping -I eth1 www.google.com

Comment: Note: This won't work on MacOS

Answer (score 4):

I believe using the `-I` option will do this. I had to do it once, but that was some time ago. From the ping man page:

-I interface address
Set  source  address  to  specified interface address. Argument may be numeric IP address or name of device. When pinging IPv6 link-local address this option is required.