# Totally isolate two interfaces -Linux

Tags: linux, networking, iproute

I'm a bit embarrassed but I need your help.

I have three interfaces on a virtual machines. I want to completely  isolate my interfaces between them.
I created one route table for each interface:

```
    inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global ens192
3: ens224: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.10.100/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global ens224
4: ens256: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.20.100/24 brd 192.168.20.255 scope global ens256
Network interface exemple:
        up /sbin/ip route add default via 192.168.10.1 dev ens224 table in
        up /sbin/ip rule add from 192.168.10.100/32 table  in
        post-down /sbin/ip rule del from 192.168.10.100/32 table  in
        post-down /sbin/ip route del default via 192.168.10.1 dev ens224 table  in
```

But when I try to telnet or ping or whatever from one interface to another one, all the traffic go through the loopback. Is there a way to correct that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/531620/230046), you can use the `-I` flag to specify an interface for `ping` to use.

Also, unless you enable `net.ipv4.ip_forward` in sysctl, the interfaces won't route between them. You can mitigate this further by dropping all FORWARD traffic with `iptables`.

If you wanted to further isolate the interfaces then I expect you could use iptables to drop traffic that has the inbound and outbound interfaces different, something like:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -i ens192 -o ens224 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -i ens192 -o ens256 -j DROP
... etc for other permutations of the 3 interfaces ...
```

Without understanding the problem space more, that's the best answer I can give.